# Using java script load workbook from tableau server non default site?

Tags: javascript, tableau-api

I'm new to java script and Tableau. My task is to build a webpage with Tableau workbook visualizations. In our company's server there are multiple sites including: Default, Site A, Site B ... and so on. The Default site includes some of the sample visualizations that every one can access. The others sites A, B,... can only accessed by certain users. I want to load the workbooks in site A, but when I put

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://company-server/#/site/siteA/javascripts/api/tableau-2.min.js"></script>

url = "https://company-server/views/SiteA/workbook/sheet"
```

in the java script. The visualizations cannot be loaded successfully. How can I fix this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer by myself. In the tableau server website, open a dashboard or a sheet. On the left upper corner, there is a "Share" button. Click and you can get the javascript api and url for this dashboard/sheet.